# Few questions of circularly symmetric complex random variables

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Asked here as well:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346148/three-questions-of-circularly-symmetric-complex-random-variables

Let $Z: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be a random variable with density $f_Z$. Note that, we're **not** assuming that $Z$ is complex Gaussian/complex normal.

My first question, just for the sake of checking, is:

(1) If $Z$ is circularly symmetric, then do we've: $f_Z(z)=f_Z(e^{i\phi}z)   \forall \phi \in \mathbb{R}$, owing to the fact that the determinant of the Jacobian of the map $z \mapsto e^{i\phi}z$ is $1$? All the literature I've consulted mentiond that *"distribution of $Z$ remains invariant under $z \to e^{i\phi}z$"*, but they never point out what it mathematically means exactly, *specially given that there're not many (if at all?) resources that describe the transformation of densities of complex random variables.*

(2) For the moment, don't assume circular symmetry of $Z$. How do you define $E[g(Z)]$ for any continuously (real) differentiable function $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}?$ Below is an attempt, but I've never seen a formal definition (reference appreciated!).

**First note that:** if $Z=X+iY$, then we *define*

$E[Z]:= E[X] + iE[Y] = \int _{\mathbb{R}} xf_X(x)dx + i \int _{\mathbb{R}} yf_Y(y)dy  $. The essence of the above definition is that the expectations of real part $X$ and imaginary part $Y$ are calculated seperately, and then put back together to obtain $E[Z]$.

But the above definition *doesn't seem to generalize* well to define $E[g(Z)]$ for any continuously (real) differentiable function $g$. For, if we write $W = g(Z) = U + iV$, then $U, V$ are functions of BOTH $x,y$, and unlike the case where $g(z)=z = x + iy$, $u,v$ may depend on both $x,y$. Hence defining $E[Z] = E[U] + iE[V]$ won't make sense.

However, going back to the example where $g(z)=z$, we can write: $E[Z]=\int _{\mathbb{R}^2}zf_{X,Y}(z)dx dy$, using the fact that : $E[X]=\int _{\mathbb{R}^2}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dx dy, E[Y]=\int _{\mathbb{R}^2}yf_{X,Y}(x,y)dx dy$, and $E[Z]:= E[X] + iE[Y].$

Note that, this new definition of $E[Z]$ by using $E[Z]=\int _{\mathbb{R}^2}zf_{X,Y}(z)dx dy$ readily generalizes to defining $E[g(Z)]$, namely:

$E[g(Z)]:= \int _{\mathbb{R}^2}g(z)f_{X,Y}(z)dx dy$

*So, finally, my question is:* **is this how we define $E[g(Z)]$?** Or is there any simpler definition?

(3) Assume again that $Z$ is circularly symmetric. Then using the defintions pointed out in (1) and (2), we readily have all the moments of $Z$ to vanish!!! Is this true? (I feel not...). But below is my calculation:

Let $m \geq 1.$ Then, by setting $z = e^{i\phi}w$, writing $w=u+iv$, by change of variables and using $du \land dv=dx\land dy$ (equal area form):

$E[Z^m]:= \int _{\mathbb{R}^2}z^m f_{X,Y}(z)dx dy = \int _{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{mi\phi} w^m f_{X,Y}(e^{i\phi}w)du dv = e^{mi\phi}\int _{\mathbb{R}^2} w^m f_{X,Y}(e^{i\phi}w)du dv = e^{mi\phi}\int _{\mathbb{R}^2} w^m f_{X,Y}(w)du dv $ (using circular symmetry, as in (1)) $= e^{mi\phi}\int _{\mathbb{R}^2}z^m f_{X,Y}(z)dx dy = e^{mi\phi} E[Z^m] $. This proves: $ E[Z^m] =0 \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm sure the proof is wrong, but where?

Comment: FYI, sometimes questions on MSE are cross-posted to MO, but that’s usually after the question has gone unanswered for some time here. You’re not actually supposed to cross-post simultaneously. (In fact I think SE rules actually expressly prohibit cross posting, but mods tend to take a lenient view toward the case I mention at the start of my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. There is no difficulty working directly with a measure on $\mathbb{C}$, which in the continuous case can be handled by a just a double integral $dx dy$. This works out how you wrote it.
3. That's right. Intuitively if you do the integrations in polar coordinates, the $d\theta$ integral vanishes for each fixed $r$. This doesn't happen if you consider $|Z|^m$, which is a natural thing to do in the circularly symmetric setting.

Comment: thanks for your answer! While I see that $E[|Z|^m]\neq 0$, the reason I had bit of doubt about $E[Z^m]$ being equal to $0$ for each $m$ was that: (1) I never found an online source that mentioned that, they just wrote that $E[Z]=E[Z^2]=0$ for circularly symetric $Z$, and never wrote about higher order moments, (2) to prove that $E[Z^m]=0$ for a specific $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we're just using the fact that: the distrubution/density of $Z$ is invariant under $z \mapsto ze^{i\phi}$ for any single $\phi \neq \frac{2\pi}{m}$, which is much weaker than the circular symmetry property.